# Issue with copy JRE into docker and run java command

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, containers, javac

I am copying the working version of the JRE directory into docker and trying to run /JRE/bin/java.
But it throws **ash: java not found** error. I am doing the same in a linux VM . Just copying the JRE folder and executing java command which works fine in VM. I don't want to download JRE from anywhere.
Want this specific JRE bundled.How to resolve this.

I entered into the shell console and navigated to the JRE/bin/ directory and executed "java". even then it fails . The error is same **ash: java not found** error.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM alpine:latest

ENV HOME=/root \
        DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
        LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \
        LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8 \
        LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 \
        DISPLAY=:0.0 \
        DISPLAY_WIDTH=1024 \
        DISPLAY_HEIGHT=768

RUN apk --update --upgrade add \
        bash \
        fluxbox \
        x11vnc \
        xterm \
        xvfb

COPY MyJavaApp MyJavaApp/
WORKDIR /MyJavaApp
ENV PATH="./JRE/bin:${PATH}"
```

Comment: Why not use a JRE docker image to build the application?

If you need a sample then you can use my docker file which i have in below link

https://github.com/naveenkulkarni029/products-api/blob/master/Dockerfile

Comment: "Just copying the JRE folder and executing java command which works fine in VM" - something tells me in your VM running Java already works without copying anything.

Comment: please share Dockerfile to understand ENV setup

Comment: Nothing in the Dockerfile you show installs Java, and you're not using a base image that would include it (`alpine` is extremely minimal).  Do you expect running `java` to work, and if so, why?

Comment: I am not installing java ..just copying JRE folder and invoking "java" from bin folder ..It works well with Linux machines .I am expecting the same from this alpine

Answer (score 1):

When are you copying the JRE directory to the docker? i.e Docker build time or after spinning up the Docker container?

Looks like you are correctly copying the local Java directory to the image, however the current location cannot access the java binaries, thus, make sure to set the PATH. It should be something like,

```
RUN export PATH=/JRE/bin:${PATH}
```

or pass the path to the ENV in the Dockerfile,

```
ENV PATH="/JRE/bin:${PATH}"
```

Comment: Thx Anuradha . But even after this it is failing . the error is "ash: java not found"

Comment: I entered into the shell console and navigated to the JRE/bin/ directory and executed "java". even then it fails . The error is same. Please let me know how to address.

Comment: Can you quickly check what's the permission level of java file there?

Comment: "-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root " is the previlege

Comment: Are you using the alpine image as the base? can we see your Dockerfile?

Comment: Yes. I am just having "FROM alpine:latest" . Please see above.

Comment: Looks like there is a compatibility issue with alpine libs and java. Have a look in here  https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/11 

I think the best way to overcome this issue is by using a java base image.

Comment: You know, how to use base image